# How to get image path from Resource files

Tags: c#

I am storing images in Resource files but the PDF Lib I am using needs image path as string in order to embed images in the output.

But honestly, I couldn't find any way to do that.

Comment: So are you building your image files as "Embedded resources"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the images to a temporary location on disk, then feed that temporary location to the PDF library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resource_name_of_the_image)` to access the image's stream, write it to TEMP directory and use this path.

For example, if you have an image file in your project at the path "**Resources\Images\Image.png**" and the project's assembly default namespace is "**RootNamespace**", you can access the image's stream from within this assembly's code with

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("RootNamespace.Resources.Images.Image.png")
```